# OnClick event doesn't work in WebPart

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a simple webpart with code below, but when I click on the button code in the "UnAcceptClick" didn't work.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
public class simple_wp : WebPart
{

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        CreateControlHierarchy();
    }

    private void CreateControlHierarchy()
    {

                unAccept.Text = "Cancel";
                unAccept.Click += new EventHandler(UnAcceptClick);

     ... some other code ... }   


    private void UnAcceptClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... some code ...
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        try
        {
             Controls.Add(unAccept); // button
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ex.ToString()));
        }

    } // # CreateChildControls #
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `CreateChildControls` , you associate in your init method not in render of application

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        try
        {
             unAccept.Click += new EventHandler(UnAcceptClick);
             Controls.Add(unAccept); // button
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ex.ToString()));
        }

    } //
```